# LIVE SERVER NO ACTUALIZA

Tags: html, css, vscode-live-server

Buen dia,

Por favor su ayuda, cuando activo el liveserver todo ok, perfecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando sigo generando codigo y guardo luego la web donde se mostraba la pagina se actualiza y se pone en blanco, pero luego refresco la pagina y aparece el codigo, pero entiendo que el liveserver deberia de actualizarse sin hacerlo manualmente, les muestro mi configuracion json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Juan, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, evitar recibir votos negativos, y acceder a una mejor respuesta, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba en armar otro perfil en el Visual e instalarlo sin muchas extensiones seguramente alguna otra que estas usando hace conflicto con la misma

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).